# Sinch Framework - Uploading Call Records in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sinch

Does anybody have information on how to make sinch framework upload the voice call recordings to AWS s3?

I've created an IAM user on AWS for this, but could not find where to set the AWS credentials so that Sinch uploads the call recording automatically. Is it done on the client side, i.e. IOS code, or done by Sinch team manually? Do we need to change anything on the client side for this behaviour?

Please let me know if you have any information regarding this.

Kind Regards,
Engin

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be set yourself. To do so, send an email to support@sinch.com.